# Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым. Указательные местоимения

Tags: пунктуация

Ставится ли тире перед указательным местоимением "то", если оно выступает в роли сказуемого? (этого я не нашла у Д.Розенталя)
Трудолюбие (-) то, что нужно для хорошей успеваемости как школьника, так и студента.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **Это то, что...** (тире не ставится)

Здесь ***это*** ― подлежащее, выраженное местоимением,  ***то*** ― указательное местоимение в роли сказуемого: тире не ставится, паузы нет.

Примеры:

Мне кажется, **это то, что** нужно. **Это то, что** касается собственных вложений. **Это то, что** мне скоро понадобится. **Это то, что** он писал незадолго до гибели.

2)  **Тире ставится, если подлежащее выражено сущ. в И.п.**

ТрУд ― основа успеха в любом деле, а **трудолЮбие ― то, что нужно для хорошей успеваемости как школьника, так и студента.**

***Трудолюбие*** ― подлежащее, выраженное существительным в И.п.,  ***то*** ― указательное местоимение в роли сказуемого.  В этом случае требуется **отделить подлежащее от сказуемого с помощью паузы и тире**, при этом логическим ударением выделено подлежащее.  Для таких высказываний характерны **параллельные** конструкции.

Пример: По их мнению, основной объединяющий **признак** для этих стран  ― **то, что** многие из них в той или иной степени являются источниками  политической и экономической нестабильности.

3) **Связки ЭТО, ВОТ** (тире ставится)

Обычно перед местоимением ***то*** находится связка ***ЭТО*** или ***ВОТ***.

Примеры:

Но настанет момент, когда этот самолет будет летать выше, быстрее, надежнее, и все поймут: ага, обратный ***угол*** крыла ― **вот то, что** надо было!

***Культура*** ― **это то, что о**стаётся, когда всё забыто

Comment: А ставится ли в таком предложении тире? 
Всё, что он сказал своему другу, (-) чистая правда.

Comment: Да. тире ставится в таких конструкциях после определительного оборота или придаточного предложения.

Comment: А это правило есть у Д. Розенталя?

Comment: У Розенталя нет специального правила на эту тему, но это общий принцип независимой постановки знаков http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=176#pp176  Это правило фактически применяется в данной конструкции, что видно из примеров. Можно посмотреть http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1325022-stavitsja-li-zapjataja-pered-tire.html

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Трудолюбие - то, что нужно для хорошей успеваемости как школьника, так и студента.

Перед местоимением *то* в роли сказуемого делается пауза и ставится тире. Оно необходимо, чтобы обозначить состав подлежащего и сказуемого.

Без паузы и тире  местоимение *то* можно  отнести к подлежащему.